# trying to figure out how to set up a centered text box

Tags: html, css

extremely new to html and css, started literally days ago, im trying to figure out how to put a text box in the center of my site with the text aligned against the left of the box with a short title and space for the date and time just using h1, then h3, then h2. Id also like it to have its own separate background than the rest of the site. I would hope it is responsive as well. [similar to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUT4P.png)

so far ive used border to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U2Ww.png), but the issue is the text isnt aligned to the left, and there is no difference in background. i understand that the top border of the desired image is a png, i would also like to know how to get that done if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply, apply a CSS property called text-align to make the text to the left. But make sure the container where you have the text has to be of width 100%.

[image]

Here is the HTML I used.

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="modal">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
        </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Here are the styles

```
<style>
      body {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande",
          "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      .container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;

        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .modal {
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 1.5rem;
        background-color: aqua;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-top: 15px solid black;

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: left;
      }
</style>
```

To get the boundaries of each box (tag/element in HTML ), you can use a temporary border around all of them by adding.

```
* {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

All the HTML tags work on BOX-Model. I also wanted to share some learning resources with you to help you out.

- HTML - [W3 Schools Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)
- CSS - [Web Dev Simplified's CSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PnVor36_40&list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH9D0J0Mtp6lIiD_8046k3si)

Comment: Mention Not. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the html pictured and the css pictured to get boxes that work the way i want, only issue is on the site they have a huge amount of space inbetween but i will find a way to remedy this shortly.

```css
.contain {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal {
  width: 50vw;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
  color: black;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
      <div class="modal">
        <h2>YIPPIE</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
        </p>
      </div>
   </div>

  <div class="container">
      <div class="modal">
        <h2>Super looooonnnggg yippie</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
        </p>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To align your text to the left within the box, you can use the CSS text-align property. This allows you to specify the alignment of text. For aligning text to the left, simply use:

```css
h1 {
text-align: left;
}
```

You can learn more about the text-align property and its values here: [MDN Web Docs on text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

Regarding the border that resembles the image you mentioned, there are several approaches you can take:

1. **Box Shadow**: You can create sophisticated border effects using the box-shadow property. It allows for a flexible way to add shadow
   effects around an element's frame, which can simulate borders. A
   great resource to experiment with and learn about box-shadow is [CSS
   Matic Box Shadow Generator](https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow).
2. **Border Image**: Another method is using the border-image property. This CSS feature enables you to use an image as the border of an
   element. It's quite versatile and can be used to achieve unique
   border designs, including the one you described. For a comprehensive
   guide and examples, visit [MDN Web Docs on border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image).
3. **Custom Element or Pseudo-Elemen**t: Lastly, you can create a custom decorative border by using a custom element (such as a div)
   or a pseudo-element (like ::before). This element can then be styled
   and positioned at the top of your message block, with its width set
   to 100% and a custom background applied to simulate the top border
   design you're after.